# How to customize heroku CLI?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I need to download my database at heroku, how to add in these flags: -a (data only), -x (no privileges), -O (no owner) to the CLI ??

Currently I use:

```
heroku pgbackups:capture
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you can pass flags to pgbackups:capture. You can, however, uses pg_dump directly.

```
pg_dump DATABASE_NAME -h DATABASE_HOST -p PORT -U USER -F c -a -x -O -f db.dump
```

You can get the database values by running `heroku pg:credentials DATABASE_URL` You can also use the plugin a colleague and I wrote: [parse_db_url](https://github.com/set5think/heroku-db-url-parser). This will let you run a command like `heroku pg:parse_db_url --format pg_dump` and get a usable pg_dump command as output.

Comment: I tried it, but now I need to upgrade pg_dump, as I got this error:

pg_dump: server version: 9.3.5; pg_dump version: 9.1.14
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch

how to do so?

Comment: Depends on your platform. If you are on a Mac you could get the latest Postgres.app (http://postgresapp.com) and use the included version of pg_dump. MacPorts and Homebrew also have packages. On Ubuntu, you'll want to install postgresql-client-9.3 (sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-9.3). For windows, I think the installers from EnterpriseDB will include pg_dump (http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload).

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I am on ubuntu